# "man say" in macOS fails

Tags: macos, mojave, command-line

macOS 10.14.4

If I type `man say` at the command line, I get the error: `man: no manual page say`.

I've checked and the file `say.1` is present in the folder `/usr/share/man/man1`. Why can `man` not find it?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the replies folks! It seems that somewhere in the dim and distant past (February, actually) I had installed https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Plan9.

I deleted it and all is well now!

Answer (score 1):

I'm on High Sierra and when I do a `man -aw say` it shows the following:

```
$ man -aw say
/usr/share/man/man1/say.1
```

Which agrees with your location as well. You can use the following command to see how `man` is attempting to display the appropriate man page for `say`:

```
$ man -d say |& grep say
  (cd '/usr/share/man' && /usr/bin/tbl '/usr/share/man/man1/say.1' | /usr/bin/groff -Wall -mtty-char -Tascii -mandoc -c | (/usr/bin/less -is || true))
```

Based on that output my `say.1` man page is located here: `/usr/share/man/man1/say.1`.

You can copy/paste this command in pieces to see where things are breaking for you as well.

For example:

```
$ cd '/usr/share/man'
$ /usr/bin/tbl '/usr/share/man/man1/say.1' | less
$ ...
$ ...
```

And keep adding pieces to see where it's failing on your end.